# Erro ObjectMapper Swift 3.2

Tags: swift, swift-3

Estou tentando atualizar minha aplicação para o iOS 11, mas o *framework ObjectMapper* está dando essa mensagem de erro.

> Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2:
>   /Users/Dev/Documents/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/TravellinkCore/Carthage/Build/iOS/ObjectMapper.framework/Modules/ObjectMapper.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

Alguém sabe de alguma atualização do *Framework* ou algo assim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente você está utilizando **Carthage**. Então você precisa recompilar os modulos utilizando o compilador do Swift 4, mesmo que seja em modo 3.2.

Primeiro você deve configurar o compilador para o *toolchain* do Xcode 9, utilizando o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Note que você deve passar o caminho para onde você salvou o Xcode-Beta.

Após isso você poderá compilar o framework em questão utilizando:

```
carthage update ObjectMapper --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

Este comando irá compilar o *framework* utilizando o *toolchain* definido no passo 1. Pode ser um pouco lento, mas após isso seu projeto deverá funcionar sem problemas.

**Nota**

Para voltar ao *toolchain* padrão execute o comando no terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Resposta [adaptada a partir desta no SO English](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45435005/3927536).

Answer (score 0):

Posso estar errado, mas em geral esse erro é corrigido dando um Product -> Clean e depois um Build. Aconteceu bastante comigo quando migrei um projeto do Xcode 8 para o 9 e tinha um build antigo do Xcode 9. Se não resolver acho que vale a pena acessar a pasta do seu projeto pela linha de comandos e usar esses dois comandos:

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Eles garantem que o seu cocoapods está com os repositórios atualizados e que seu projeto tem a última versão do objectmapper e dos outros pods (a menos que você tenha especificado o contrário no PodFile, claro).

Comment: Isso funciona se você estiver utilizando `CocoaPods` para gerenciar as dependências ou estiver fazendo integração manuel, no caso do `Carthage` precisa ser do jeito explicado na minha resposta.